# GRUB boot loader error when installing Ubuntu in dual UEFI boot along side Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have some trouble installing Ubuntu on my new computer. I encountered [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZcJ9.png) and I did not find a solution to my problem yet.

I disabled secure boot and fast boot. Here is what I want to achieve as a configuration (images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgcbz.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOx9S.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5iW.png)). I wonder why there is all these mini-partition as well. Is Windows doing that?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/QKA9VMt0) is what I found in my /var/log/syslog file. I grep on "grub" since the error seems to come from it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post results from terminal in Live for `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0):

The installer can't write grub to the intended partition for some reason. Is your NVME drive compatible with your BIOS/motherboard? I have an older 4th gen system and I can't boot directly from my Intel Optane drive because the BIOS does not have the NVME boot code. However, I was able to put grub on my SATA SSD in the EFI boot partition and the rest of the OS is on the Optane drive which the BIOS sees as a regular device (which is very snappy over the SSD by the way) so it only uses the SSD to load grub and the boot menu. The rest of the SSD has Windows and data partitions like normal.

Also ensure your partitions are GPT not MSDOS. And it's a good idea to create the partitions before you start the installation. You can do this with the Live OS option, then install the full OS.